# Angular 6 - Promise<any> is not assignable to type LeagueTable

Tags: angular, typescript

New to Angular and I'm trying to get the JSON League Table data from the api but I am getting **Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'LeagueTable'**.

**leaguetable.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';

  const baseUrl = 'http://api.football-data.org/v1';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LeaguetableService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getLeagueTable() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('X-Auth-Token', 'apikey');
    return this.http.get(baseUrl +'/competitions/445/leagueTable', { headers: headers })
   .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()));
  }

}
```

**leaguetable.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LeagueTable } from '../league-table';
import { LeaguetableService } from '../leaguetable.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-leaguetable',
  templateUrl: './leaguetable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./leaguetable.component.css']
})
export class LeaguetableComponent implements OnInit {

  leagueTable: LeagueTable;

  constructor(private leagueTableService: LeaguetableService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLeagueTable();
  }

  getLeagueTable() {
    this.leagueTableService.getLeagueTable().subscribe(leagueTable => this.leagueTable = leagueTable);
  }
}
```

**league-table.ts**

```
export class LeagueTable {
  leagueCaption: string;
  matchday: number;
  standing: ({ 
    rank: number;
    team: string;
    teamId: number;
    playedGames: number;
    crestURI: string;
    points: number;
    goals: number;
    goalsAgainst: number;
    goalDifference: number;
  })
}
```

I'm not exactly sure why this is happening, any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Added class file for more clarification.

Comment: `.pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()))` is for Http. It should be omitted in HttpClient. There are no promises involved in the code you've posted, only observables, so it's unclear how you could get this error message.

Answer (score 0):

With the intention to edit my answer, You seem to try to be assigning res.json() which returns a promise to leagueTable, which is a LeagueTable. If you wanted to return a promise, you must use then() in your subscribe block and try assigning the value there. I'd suggest to try removing the pipe and map and just returning the observable, and subscribing to it as you are.

Same as above comments:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';

  const baseUrl = 'http://api.football-data.org/v1';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LeaguetableService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getLeagueTable() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('X-Auth-Token', 'apikey');
    // Just returning the observable from get()
    return this.http.get(baseUrl +'/competitions/445/leagueTable', { headers: headers });
  }

}
```

Comment: Hey mate, so I removed the pipe and map but now I'm getting  error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'LeagueTable'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
src/app/leaguetable/leaguetable.component.ts(21,97): error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'LeagueTable'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Property 'leagueCaption' is missing in type 'Object'.. Added class file to op

Comment: Ok that means the return is an object (which could be anything in js). Could you do a console.log() of the output of the observable? I'm guessing it isn't formed to your object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';

  const baseUrl = 'http://api.football-data.org/v1';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LeaguetableService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getLeagueTable() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('X-Auth-Token', 'apikey');
    // Just returning the observable from get()
    return this.http.get(baseUrl +'/competitions/445/leagueTable', { headers: headers })
    .map(res => res.json());
  }

}



import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LeagueTable } from '../league-table';
import { LeaguetableService } from '../leaguetable.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-leaguetable',
  templateUrl: './leaguetable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./leaguetable.component.css']
})
export class LeaguetableComponent implements OnInit {

  leagueTable: LeagueTable;

  constructor(private leagueTableService: LeaguetableService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLeagueTable();
  }

  getLeagueTable() {
    this.leagueTableService.getLeagueTable().subscribe(leagueTable => {
      console.log(leagueTable);
      this.leagueTable = leagueTable
    });
  }
}
```